# scroll markers not triggered

Tags: javascript, scroll

In my scroll event listener  I loop through all my .project elements then add or remove a class depending on their current position from the top of the viewport.  I want to add a class to an element when it is at 80% of viewport height and remove it at  100% and 0%.

The logic I have should work fine, but the class rarely gets added at all.

```js
var projects = document.querySelectorAll(".project");
var counter = document.getElementById("counter");

var viewH = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight;

window.addEventListener(
  "scroll",
  function() {
    

      for (var i = 0; i < projects.length; i++) {

        var project = projects[i];

        // get dist from top of viewport 
        distTop = project.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        distPercent = Math.round(distTop / viewH * 100);

        // play at 80% 
        if (distPercent == "80") {
          project.classList.add("play");
          counter.innerHTML = i + 1;
        }

        // stop at 0% 
        if (distPercent == "0") {
          project.classList.remove("play");
        }
        
        // stop if off screen 
        if (distPercent =="100") {
          project.classList.remove("play");
        }
      }
    
  },
  false
);

window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
 viewH = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight;
})
```

```css
#half {
  position:fixed;
  top:50%;
  height: 1px;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
}

#projects {
  padding-top:60vh;
  width: 50vw;
  margin: 0 auto;

}

#counter {
  position: fixed;
  top:20px;
  left: 20px;
  font-size:20px
}


.project {
background:pink;
    height: 50vh;
    width: 50vw;
    margin-bottom:100px;
   transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.play {background:red}


* {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="half"></div>

<div id="counter">0</div>

<div id="projects">

  <div class="project">1</div>
  <div class="project">2</div>
  <div class="project">3</div>
  <div class="project">4</div>
  <div class="project">5</div>

</div>
```

Comment: I guess sometimes it would be hard to get exactly 80%, you can try with a range, maybe **if (distPercent >= 77 && distPercent <= 83)** to add the class and **<=3** or **=> 97** to remove it.